# How to implement div as marker in to google maps api

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Is there any possibilities in google maps api to implement **div* as marker. I have seen almost similar one in a national geographic website. but unfortunately keep on fail when implement that function in to my map :(

Does it work when use as opened infoindow ?

```
var options = {
    zoom: 14,
    center: mycity,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};
```

My work  http://jsfiddle.net/gbqzQ/2/

looking for something like this **working demo:-**http://natgeo125.appspot.com/ [image]

Comment: You should use InfoBox - https://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobox/docs/reference.html#InfoBox

Comment: @user3388636 Thanks for your reply, from your point of view does it work similar this website http://natgeo125.appspot.com/ when use infowindow ?

Comment: @user3388636 which one you prefer use as infowindow or use a cirlce like this http://jsbin.com/nuwem/2/edit ?

Comment: Circle is just circle...